# What exactly is a Christian Witch?

Tags: conversion, witchcraft

I am a Wiccan looking into converting into Christianity. Doing some research, I know that the Lord is against witchcraft. So why is there even such a thing as a Christian Witch, and what are they?

Comment: Which denominations have witches? None that I am aware of!

Comment: Hi person, glad to see you're giving Christ a shot.  I'm not sure we've got a ton of answers for you, I haven't seen anybody post anything here about Christian Witches. You'll probably have to explain where you heard of it.   There were many Druid and Norse converts in the dark ages, as far as I know, they become regular old fashioned Catholics.  I can tell for certain that there's no approve cult within mainline Christian denominations that approves of witchcraft.  So this has the mark of an esoteric question.

Comment: Sorry for absence, I had to mess with the wifi, anyways, I heard the reference from a Wiccan website, detailing the many traditions. I saw Chriso-Pagainism and came back to it once I converted.

Comment: also, if you would, in which chapter of the Bible are the 10 commandments detailed?

Comment: exodus 20 has the 10 commandments

Comment: A Christian witch is one who has gone to the dark side!

Comment: a Christian witch might be a confused wiccan

Comment: If you would please indicate a source or book or article that explains where this idea was formed or where you got it, that would be helpful in forming an answer.  **I heard the reference from a Wiccan website** Which one?   Where? What's the url?

Answer (score 1):

This is not something I had ever heard of and I have only done some brief digging but, here are my (protestant) 2 cents.

This is from the [website](https://northernway.org/cpinfo.html) of the Esoteric Interfaith Church describing what Christo-paganism purports to be.  Here you can become **ordained today!** and/or earn degrees from bachelors to PhD.

> What is this term, Christo-Pagan or Christian-Pagan? Isn’t it a contradiction?  Well, the truth is: your ancestors were probably Christo-Pagans.  In Europe the historical Dual Faith period lasted from approximately 450 AD to 1100 AD, some say it began with Christianity itself. Indeed, Christianity has undeniable pagan roots.

There are some charts and explanations (not overly burdened by evidence) describing the pagan and gnostic roots of not only certain Christian practices (Quakers and Old Catholics (?) are mentioned) but also forms of Judaism, Zen Buddhism, and Taoism.

There is also some poorly understood [early Church history](https://northernway.org/pagandna.html) detailing how the Nicene council was a superficially Christian, predominantly pagan device used by the pagan Constantine to consolidate pagan factions into what became the Roman Catholic Church so as to choose sides in the earliest Christian schism between gnostics and pistics.  There is so much more but it appears to be a hot mess of jumbled fact, mythologized history, and baseless speculation.  The statue of Peter in Rome is said to actually be the statue of Jupiter (Jo-Peter), for example.

There is also, according to the Esoteric Interfaith Church, a full return to the embrace of the Feminine Divine which provides a balance that resonates with the natural.

> One of the things modern Dual-Faithers bring back to Christianity is the presence of the Feminine Divine. Too long has Christianity been a lopsided masculine only “family” of God. Ironic that mainstream Christianity uses the phrase “family of God” since it is a dysfunctional family with no females, daughters or spouses. Humans naturally resonate with and respond to both a God and a Goddess. Christo-Paganism restores a much needed balance.

The idea seems to be that Roman Catholicism has hung on to and developed some aspects of it's pagan roots such as a highly inflated Mariology reflecting only a partial departure from the original 'Feminine Divine', and so many others.

[Another website](http://www.christopaganism.com/what-is-christo-paganism/) indicates that Christo-paganism is, at heart, a release from patristic human doctrines imposed on the church by men.

> So what is Christo-Paganism? It is a shedding of the doctrine of man imposed on the church. A way of washing away what doesn’t align with the true intent of God as well as a journey into the vast world of Pagan arts, sciences, and theories of what it all means when it comes to our existence.

It appears that a Christian Witch, at least as described in the small amount of research represented here, is a person who is attempting to honor the Scriptures in some way (possibly in word only) while at the same time outright rejecting vast acreage of clear biblical truth.  There appears to be a deliberate use and misrepresentation of difficult to ascertain history, mixed with mythology, and designed to deflate the primacy of the inspired Scriptures (including, but not limited to, equal appeal to canonical and non-canonical books).  This all works together to make it not only easy but beneficial for the aspiring Christo-Pagan to take what is wanted from the Bible, from whatever paganism suits, from science, from mysticism, from wherever, and to create one's own mish-mosh of personal deity, belief, and practice.

Christianity says that there is one God that has self-revealed to humanity first and generally in Creation, second and specifically in the 66 books of the Bible, and finally and personally in Jesus Christ, the Son of God.  Christianity says that while some of what is written in Scripture is difficult to understand, much of it is quite clear and none of it is disposable or takes second place to history, tradition, or personal preference.

Christianity says very clearly that, rather than the many and various paths of Christo-Paganism, there is but one, narrow path to God.

> Enter by the narrow gate. For the gate is wide and the way is easy that leads to destruction, and those who enter by it are many. For the gate is narrow and the way is hard that leads to life, and those who find it are few. - Matthew 7:13-14
>
> Jesus said to him, “I am the way, and the truth, and the life. No one comes to the Father except through me. - John 14:6

In short I would say that it is impossible to be and remain a Christian Pagan because:

a) a Christian has rejected and is in the lifelong process of identifying and abandoning in themselves every belief and practice that is contrary to what Scripture teaches. Christianity is a continual elevation of the Word of God.

> We destroy arguments and every lofty opinion raised against the knowledge of God, and take every thought captive to obey Christ,  - 2 Corinthians 10:5

b) the Christo-Pagan actively discards and dismisses Scriptural revelation whenever it is necessary for the accommodation of conflicting beliefs and practices.  Christo-Paganism is a process of bringing God's Word down to a level equal to other sources of 'revelation'.

If you are truly considering conversion **to** Christianity it must also be a conversion **from** Wicca.  From personal experience it will be very difficult (like dying) and you must pour yourself into the Scriptures (John is a good place to start) and desire for God to reveal Christ to you at the expense of everything else.  He will respond!

> You will seek me and find me, when you seek me with all your heart. - Jeremiah 29:13
>
> And without faith it is impossible to please him, for whoever would draw near to God must believe that he exists and that he rewards those who seek him. - Hebrews 11:6

Comment: Sounds like more than two cents. lol

Comment: Sounds like a best answer to me! +1

Answer (score 0):

A Christian Witch is obviously an oxymoron. No person can really be a Christian and a Witch at the same time